# Why won't AddExplosionForce work in my code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What is wrong with this code? When i fire the Rocket, it does not effect the character.

I have tried Looking other places etc but nothing really helps. I already got help so now at least the code actually runs.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Rocket : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Public changable things
    public float speed = 20.0f;
    public float life = 5.0f;
    public float explosionForce = 1.0f;
    public float explosionRadius = 1.0f;
    public bool isGrounded;

    public Rigidbody rb;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Invoke("Kill", life);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        if (isGrounded)
        {
            Kill();
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
    }
    //
    void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            isGrounded = false;
        }
    }
    //Explosion code
    void Kill()
    {
        Vector3 explosionCenterPosition = transform.position;
        rb.AddExplosionForce(explosionForce, explosionCenterPosition, explosionRadius);

        Destroy(gameObject);

    }
}
```

I am making a game where you rocket jump like TF2. It should also move other rigidbodys like described here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddExplosionForce.html

I'm new to unity and have no clue why this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

@bobshellby

you are destroying the rocket object in the same frame that you are applying the explosion force. so before you see the explosion effects the rocket will be destroyed.

Try using coroutine for the kill function, that way you can add wait time.

```
void Start()
{
    //Invoke("Kill", life);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    transform.position += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    if (isGrounded)
    {
      StartCoroutine( Kill());
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }
}
//
void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
    {
        isGrounded = false;
    }
}
//Explosion code
IEnumerator Kill()
{
    Vector3 explosionCenterPosition = transform.position;
    rb.AddExplosionForce(explosionForce, explosionCenterPosition, explosionRadius);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    Destroy(gameObject);

}
```

The other thing is you are invoking the kill function after 5second in start itself which again destroy the rocket. Remove that, as you are already checking it in update if the rocket has hit the ground or not.

Comment: You can specify a timer in the Destroy function aswell, but using a couroutine allow for more control

Comment: Yes, I do agree with you @Jichael. But as he is new to unity, its better to teach him the ropes of unity.

Comment: @murtaza Sorry for the delay i was off school for a bit but now im back and still trying to deal with this headache of a code lol.

It doesnt apply any explosion force that i can tell and it doesn't effect the player as it should.

Comment: @bobshellby sorry for the delay. I was on a sabbatical from work.
Did you find a turn around for the issue ?

Did you try changing the force value and see if it helps ?